# How can we hide multiple files in one file

Tags: windows-7, windows, alternate-data-stream

How can I combine two text files into one text file in windows?

I have seen somewhere else that it is possible.

There is something in your current notepad document which opens another document which you have inside the file.

**Note that the reported size of the text file won't be changed at all.**

Comment: Well the obvious answer is open one text file. Select it all and Copy it. Than open the other text file and paste it.

Comment: no! there is something in notepad which opens another document which you have hidden it i think .

Comment: I have edited the question for clarity. (Jonah's comment was made earlier - see edit history of question to make better sense of early comments)

Answer (score 3):

If you are talking about alternate data streams (as suggested by @Joey), an ADS can be opened in notepad like this:

```
notepad file1.txt:other.txt
```

An example of this, including running [**Streams from sysinternals**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897440.aspx).

[image]

You can do much more with this, including [**attaching executables and so forth**](http://www.wikistc.org/wiki/Alternate_data_streams).

Answer (score 1):

Just use the copy command in MS-DOS:

```
copy file1.txt+file2.txt file3.txt
```

Comment: this will change the file size . I don't want to change it , there is some tricks that with some shortcuts you can open another notepad file which doesnot exist.

Comment: What do you mean with "change the file size"? I will create a new file (file3.txt) with the content of file1.txt plus the content of file2.txt.

Comment: there is some commands in a text file that runs another ones

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you seem to mean alternate data streams. If so, then the following will write `file1` into a different stream of `file2`:

```
type file1 > file2:foo
```

Display it again with

```
more < file2:foo
```

Comment: maybe but, I mean how can we hide multiple files in a one file.

Comment: Use a different stream?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like you are looking for [how to use NTFS alternate data streams](http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=security/altds) to embed text inside another file.